# How to make an API call from a RESTful service in Java?

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, restful-url

I am new to the restful web services. So my knowledge is minimal about the topic. I am developing a restful service in Java & I want to call an Amazon web service API from inside the service. Is this possible? How many ways can I do this?

Comment: This is off-topic - please describe a specific problem you are having once you've done some basic research (the web is full of RESTful service examples and AWS is very well documented) and have attempted to write something yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference to any other java program. Just call the URL using a HTTP Client. A popular one ist the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) from [Apache HttpComponent](http://hc.apache.org/).

Comment: There's more to invoking AWS than a simple HTTP request and while you could make the request using Http Client, it's much easier to use the APIs that Amazon provide

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) framework. If I understand you correctly, you should find [this section](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) of the documentation useful.